# Combinatorics Summation Formula Derivations

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Use the summation formula

$$\sum_{a\leq n< b}{n\choose p}={b\choose p+1}-{a\choose p+1}$$

To derive

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k+1\choose 2}={n+2\choose3}$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k+p-1\choose p}={n+p\choose p+1},\quad p=1,2,3,\dots$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n{k+1\choose2}=\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}{j\choose2}=\sum_{2\le\ j<n+2}{j\choose2}={n+2\choose2+1}-\underbrace{{2\choose2+1}}_{=0,\text{ since }2<3}={n+2\choose3}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n{k+p-1\choose p}=\sum_{j=p}^{n+p-1}{j\choose p}=\sum_{p\le\ j<n+p}{j\choose p}={n+p\choose p+1}-\underbrace{{p\choose p+1}}_{=0,\text{ since }p<p+1}={n+p\choose p+1}$$